# Why is Gmail converting spaces to "+" in image src?

Tags: email, gmail, html-email

I am testing some HTML emails that I will be sending out to customers, and I have hit a problem when it comes to the images in Gmail.

The image I'm including in the email is sourced from the live website. All other email clients are loading up the images, but Gmail is giving me broken images.

I've worked out that the problem is due to the spacing in the image filenames. Gmail is converting the spaces to a "+".

e.g
https://www.test.com/files/a product image.jpg   ---> https://www.test.com/files/a+product+image.jpg

I have tried to replace the image link spaces with %20 but gmail is still converting these to "+" and therefore breaking the image.

I understand that images ideally shouldn't have spaces in them, but the website contains thousands of products, and changing the filenames is not an option in this case.

Does anybody know the reason why Gmail would change a space to a + ? Or even better, a way to fix this problem?

Thanks

Luke

Comment: A raw space is not allowed in a URL, while `%20` and `+` should be equivalent in a URL. It sounds like there is an issue with your server if it can't handle `+` properly.

Comment: If this applies to just one or a few images download them and put them on a web server yourself.

Comment: There are thousands of images, and the image chosen will depend on the product selected by the customer. All this needs to happen automatically so that is not an option. I will look into the server and see if it is handling the + correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

URL cannot contain spaces, those need to be encoded as `+` or `%20`. See [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-2.2)

> The space character is unsafe

and

> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question due to an email marketing campaign that had been sent out by a client. Some of the images embedded in the email had spaces in the filenames and consequently, some email providers did not render them correctly in the email campaign.  The client asked if I could somehow retrospectively fix it so they did not have to resend (a large recipient list)

So while this is a (very) late answer, it's still relevant

Interestingly Gmail adds a "+" sign, while other email providers (Outlook) allow the space and simply add the "%20" html percent encoding...

My fix: if you for some reason can't modify the original image file stored on the server to remove spaces, you could simply place a .htaccess rule to redirect the URL (on Apache server) as follows;

```
redirect 301 /images/staff/john+does.jpg https://example.com/images/staff/john%20does.jpg
```

When the recipient reloaded the email campaign, the broken images all loaded up :)